# JS Скрипт для консоли

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня не очень большой опыт в JS, но мне нужно сделать небольшой скрипт. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли вообще такое сделать с помощью JS?

Суть скрипта следующая:
Его нужно вставлять в консоль браузера на одном сайте. Скрипт должен выполнить определенные действия на этой странице(Это уже реализовано), дальше нужно сделать так, чтобы этот же скрипт каким то образом выполнил действия на другой странице этого же сайта. Тут у меня и возникли проблемы. Я сейчас пытаюсь сделать это с помощью document.write(). Я подтягиваю весь HTML код нужной мне страницы и вставляю его в текущую страницу через document.write(). Но после этих действий, JS не выполняет действия на новой странице(Нужно сделать клик по элементу). Я так понимаю, это из за того, что document.write() меняет страницу только визуально, а JS скрипт не может найти нужные элементы в коде.

```
setTimeout(function (){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://qna.habr.com/q/990671?from=questions_most", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function (){

  $('a[data-question="990671"]').click();

}, 5000);
```

Клик нужно сделать не на хабре, это просто для примера.
При выполнении этого кода

```
$('a[data-question="990671"]').click();
```

Я получаю такое сообщение:

```
n.fn.init [a.question__invate-expert, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "a[data-question="990671"]"]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать клик скриптом на другой странице? Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Нет, это невозможно.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, вам скорее нужно средство автоматизации действий в браузере, например, библиотека для Node.js https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/ Так у вас будет единая точка управления, из которой можно выполнять код и эмулировать действия на разных страницах в нужном порядке.